# How to run gif one time in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, animated-gif

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
root = Tk()

frameCnt = 12
frames = [PhotoImage(file='mygif.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt)]

def update(ind):

    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to run file gif one time when i opened window .
this code run gif infinity.

Comment: You're already doing a check for `if ind == frameCnt`. Just exit the function instead of resetting the count.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate the GIF only once, you don't need to reset the index as said by Bryan's comment.

Hard-coded `frameCnt` is not flexible because it need to be changed if another GIF image is used.

Also using `tkinter.PhotoImage()` to load frames from a GIF image is a bit slow when comparing with `Pillow` module, so I would suggest to use `Pillow` module.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

im = Image.open('mygif.gif')
frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame) for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)]

def update(idx=0):
    if idx < len(frames):
        label.configure(image=frames[idx])
        root.after(100, update, idx+1)

update() # start the animation
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan Oakley commented, we're already checking the count, so we just exit the function.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
root = Tk()

frameCnt = 12
frames = [PhotoImage(file='mygif.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(frameCnt)]

def update(ind):
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    label.configure(image=frame)
    if ind == frameCnt:
        return
    root.after(500, update, ind)
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```